Problema al volver mi programa con kivy en app .apk para android en la terminal de linux usando buildozer
Tengo un programa llamado AquaAlert y está compuesto por archivos .py, .png y .kv, cada uno en carpetas distintas, lo que pasa es que quiero pasar el programa a una app .apk para android y estoy usando buildozer a traves de la terminal de linux, he seguido esta guía para hacerlo:
Convertir un archivo .py a uno .apk usando Buildozer con la terminal de Linux:
Instalar Buildozer con: pip3 install buildozer
Inicializar Buildozer en tu proyecto: buildozer init
Modificar el Archivo buildozer.spec poniendo:
package.name: Nombre de tu aplicación.
package.domain: Dominio personalizado (ejemplo: org.informatikspace.app).
source.include_exts: Añadir las extensiones necesarias, como .py, .kv, etc.

Compilar un .apk para Android: buildozer -v android debug
Pero al llegar a esta parte: Compilar un .apk para Android: buildozer -v android debug, me da error:
Error:
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/bradalis/Desktop/Lenguajesdeprogramacion/Python/Hackathons/AquaAlert/bin
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/bradalis/Desktop/Lenguajesdeprogramacion/Python/Hackathons/AquaAlert/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /mnt/c/users/bradalis/Desktop/Lenguajesdeprogramacion/Python/Hackathons/AquaAlert/.buildozer/android/app
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/bredalis/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run ['git', 'clone', '-b', 'master', '--single-branch', 'https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git', 'python-for-android']
# Cwd /mnt/c/users/bradalis/Desktop/Lenguajesdeprogramacion/Python/Hackathons/AquaAlert/.buildozer/android/platform
Clonando en 'python-for-android'...



error: RPC falló; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 7819 bytes de cuerpo se siguen esperando
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: EOF temprano
fatal: fetch-pack: salida de index-pack no válida
# Command failed: ['git', 'clone', '-b', 'master', '--single-branch', 'https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git', 'python-for-android']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     WSL2_GUI_APPS_ENABLED = '1'
#     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'kali-linux'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_se = '\x1b[0m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_so = '\x1b[01;33m'
#     NAME = 'BTS'
#     PWD = '/mnt/c/users/bradalis/Desktop/Lenguajesdeprogramacion/Python/Hackathons/AquaAlert'
#     LOGNAME = 'bredalis'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/bredalis/.Xauthority'
#     HOME = '/home/bredalis'
#     LANG = 'es_ES.UTF-8'
#     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/87_interop'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=00:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.avif=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:*~=00;90:*#=00;90:*.bak=00;90:*.crdownload=00;90:*.dpkg-dist=00;90:*.dpkg-new=00;90:*.dpkg-old=00;90:*.dpkg-tmp=00;90:*.old=00;90:*.orig=00;90:*.part=00;90:*.rej=00;90:*.rpmnew=00;90:*.rpmorig=00;90:*.rpmsave=00;90:*.swp=00;90:*.tmp=00;90:*.ucf-dist=00;90:*.ucf-new=00;90:*.ucf-old=00;90::ow=30;44:'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_mb = '\x1b[1;31m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_me = '\x1b[0m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_md = '\x1b[1;36m'
#     USER = 'bredalis'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_ue = '\x1b[0m'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_us = '\x1b[1;32m'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/mnt/wslg/runtime-dir'
#     WSLENV = ''
#     PATH = ('/home/bredalis/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/bredalis/.local/bin:/home/bredalis/.local/bin:/home/bredalis/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/nodejs/:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/.cargo/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/:/mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Launcher/:/mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft '
 'VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Bradalis/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Program '
 'Files/WindowsApps/Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.12.11271.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe')
#     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
#     PULSE_SERVER = 'unix:/mnt/wslg/PulseServer'
#     OLDPWD = '/mnt/c/users/bradalis/Desktop/Lenguajesdeprogramacion/Python/Hackathons/AquaAlert/.buildozer'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

Investigue un poco y me aparecio que debía ir a esta página de GitHub: https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android e instalar manualmente el archivo en .zip, luego descomprimirlo en la carpeta .buildozer/android/platform y después que vuelva a ejecutar el mismo último comando: buildozer -v android debug, lo hice pero ya no se que hacer, sigue dando el mismo error 

No conozco ese error en concreto, pero si que es verdad que usando la terminal de Linux local de mi PC me daba muchísimos errores a la hora de compilar con buildozer, te recomiendo que pruebes un entorno limpio el que más te guste o te convezca, yo he usado los Notebooks de Google Colab ahi seguro que te funciona, eso sí tardas un poco más de tiempo, a la hora de compilar, a menos que pagues claro. Te dejo este video por si te ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZkXHx3pJpM

Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente reputación podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Es mejor dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta. - Desde revisión
